# Como usar @sqlstatement no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Como posso fazer uma melhor utilização da variável @sqlstatement no SQL Server, não consegui entender qual sua real função.

Por favor, poderia me explicar e deixar alguns exemplos?

Peço que se possível não utilizem de imagem pois sou deficiente visual e os leitores não conseguem ler prints.

Comment: Não entendi bem. Que eu saiba, esse é um nome de variável como qualquer outro. Mas pelo nome, suponho que contenha uma instrução SQL. É isso? Nesse caso, você pode usar [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) para executar a instrução contida na variável.

Comment: Também não entendi a pergunta, essa não é uma palavra reservada e parece que você está com problemas para entender um exemplo específico de código. Por favor reformule a pergunta e poste o código que vc não está entendendo